# Excel Fill from another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

My issue isn't setting up the formula that grabs the data from another sheet, it's filling the data with Excel's fill tool.  So I don't have to tediously type/click every cell, etc.

This is my issue:

The following formula,

`='Daily Totals'!A1`,

is in `sheet 2`.  I'm displaying the data in rows in `sheet 2`, but columns in `sheet 1`, which is where I think Excel is having issues `filling`.  What I want to occur is

`='Daily Totals'!A2`

`='Daily Totals'!A3`

What excel is doing is

`='Daily Totals'!B1`

`='Daily Totals'!C1`.

Is there anyway to fix my issue?  Or am I stuck manually editing cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula in cell A1 and copy to the right

```
=INDEX('Daily Totals'!$A:$A,COLUMN())
```

Adjust the last parameter by adding a 1 if you want to start with DailyTotals!A2 instead of A1

[image]

Comment: sorta worked other than the fill just repeating the last number input.  should mention my issue isn't so cut and dry as what I posted, just tried to cut out the unnecessary stuff.

Comment: I use `=INDEX('Daily Totals'!$F:$F,3)`, try to fill across the row and it just repeats the same thing.

Comment: Anndddd scratch that, just had to adjust the code to `=INDEX('Daily Totals'!$F:$F,COLUMN()-1) for whatever reason.  It was starting on column 4, whereas I needed column 3.  Thanks for the help!